PyQt5 - How can I have scaling handles on the selected image
I'm trying to create a basic image viewer with just a few features.

Can add/remove images
Can move/drag images.
Can rotate images
Can scale images

I don't know how to add control handles around a selected image so that I can change scale(not crop) of the image by moving those handles. Here is my code so far:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QFileDialog, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage, QPen, QColor, QTransform
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRectF

class ImageViewer(QMainWindow):


 def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
    self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
    self.view.setMouseTracking(True)

    self.image_item = None
    self.selection_rect = None

    self.zoom_factor = 1.0

    layout = QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.view)

    self.button_add_image = QPushButton("Add Image")
    self.button_add_image.clicked.connect(self.add_image)
    layout.addWidget(self.button_add_image)

    self.slider_rotate = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
    self.slider_rotate.setMinimum(0)
    self.slider_rotate.setMaximum(360)
    self.slider_rotate.setValue(0)
    self.slider_rotate.setTickInterval(1)
    self.slider_rotate.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBelow)
    self.slider_rotate.valueChanged.connect(self.rotate_image)
    layout.addWidget(self.slider_rotate)

    widget = QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    self.setCentralWidget(widget)


 def add_image(self):
    file_path, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Image File", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")
    if file_path:
        image = QImage(file_path)
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(image)
        self.image_item = QGraphicsPixmapItem(pixmap)
        self.scene.addItem(self.image_item)

def wheelEvent(self, event):
    if event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier:
        delta = event.angleDelta().y() / 120
        self.zoom_factor += delta * 0.1
        self.view.resetTransform()
        self.view.scale(self.zoom_factor, self.zoom_factor)

def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if self.image_item and self.image_item.isUnderMouse():
        self.image_item.setFlag(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.image_item.setFlag(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsSelectable)

def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if self.image_item:
        self.image_item.setFlag(QGraphicsPixmapItem.ItemIsMovable, False)

def rotate_image(self):
    if self.image_item:
        rotation = self.slider_rotate.value()
        center = self.image_item.boundingRect().center()
        transform = QTransform().translate(center.x(), center.y()).rotate(rotation).translate(-center.x(), -center.y())
        self.image_item.setTransform(transform)
        if self.selection_rect:
            self.selection_rect.setTransform(transform)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = ImageViewer()
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Can anyone please help me with this.
Thanks.

You should normally avoid handling mouse events from parents, especially in the case of graphics view and its items. At the very least, this should be done within the widget itself, and for graphics view it means the view or its scene. In most cases, and most importantly when more resizable items may exist, the most appropriate approach is to implement mouse events in the resizable item class, or even in its children (the "handles"). There is no absolute best or preferred approach, it always depends on each case and program purpose, also considering relative coordinate systems.
